# Apache poi, output to excel in single column

Tags: java, apache

I have 3 different array lists that need to be exported to a excel spreadsheet using apache poi. The problem I am having is in the format they print to the sheet. Is there a way to have one of the arraylists print straight down a single column?

Answer (score 1):

To print straight down a single column you can try this code.

```
Sheet sheet = ....;

for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue(array1.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void createCellAndSetValue(HSSFRow row1, int i, String value,HSSFSheet sheet,HSSFCellStyle style) {
    HSSFCell cell=row1.createCell(i);
    setCellValue(cell, value);
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    setCellStyle(cell, style);
    style.setWrapText(true);
}

     for (int i = 0; i < list.Size(); i++) {
          HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(count);
          createCellAndSetValue(row,1,list.get(i),sheet,style);
          createCellAndSetValue(row,2,listOne.get(i),sheet,style);
        }
```