# putting a value in a single cell through loop using poi in java

Tags: java, newline, apache-poi

I have a String in the following format:

`abcd|1|2,pqr|2|3......`

I want to output the following in a single cell:

```
abcd|1|2
pqr|2|3
```

I am splitting the string on the `,` character.

The string value is coming from another loop

```
for(ActivityDTO activity : activityList) {

    HSSFCell cell6 = dataRowAct.createCell(6);
    String str[] = string.split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        cell6.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(str[i]+"\n"));
    }
}
```

But in excel I only get the last value as the old value overwites.

Comment: Can we see where you have declared your `cell6`?

Comment: In above code for cell6 the last value will be assigned.So,we need create different cells for setting values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12072434/1211000

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're repeatedly setting the value of cell6. It will end up being the value of whatever yoy set it as last, which matches up with the problem you're having. Depending on what you want to end up with, you need to change the cell that is being set in your for loop. i.e, change cell6 to something else depending on what i you're on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *build* a String (using a StringBuilder) then print the final result to the cell.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    sb.append(str[i] + "\n");
}

cell6.setCellValue(sb.toString());
```

As an alternative...

If you simply want to replace `,` characters with newlines, you can use [String.replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) like this:

```
String s = "abcd|1|2,pqr|2|3";
cell6.setCellValue(s.replace(",", "\n"));
```

This replaces each occurrence of `,` with a newline.

Comment: I think he wants to add each in different cells not to append the values in the same cell. otherwise he would not have to split it

Comment: I don't see any evidence that this is the case.  It looks like he's splitting it so he can print the String on multiple lines (yes, he could just use String.replace() in stead).  He says: _I want to output the following in a cell._ There is no mention of multiple cells.

Comment: @user1697114 If you liked his answer, remember to click the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm right
You want the whole in one cell

```
abcd|1|2
```

so

```
   String str[] = string.split(",");
   int r=//row number
   Row row=sheet.createRow(r);
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    cell6.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(str[i]+"\n"));
    cell6=sheet.createRow(++r).createCell(/*cellnumber*/);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are removing old value.

```
   String s="";
   for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
     s+=str[i]+"\n";
   }
   cell6.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(s));
```

Comment: I think he wants to add each in different cells not to append the values in the same cell. otherwise he would not have to split it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your **cell6** here. Anyway the logic should be like:

```
cell6.setCellValue(cell6.getCellValue()+str[i]+"\n"));
```